# Compute $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am having a weird problem .

I am unable to compute $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}$.

As I took $x\to 0$ from the left hand side then $\frac{1}{x}\to -\infty $ and as I took $x\to 0$ from the right hand side then $\frac{1}{x}\to 
+\infty $

**So the question is what should I say that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}=\infty$ or should I say that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}$ does not exist**?Please help.

I am having hard time here.Please give some suggestions.

Comment: It depends on what is the topology of the extended real line you are considering. Usually one says that the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit does not exist. As you approach x=0 from the right the function approaches positive infinity, while the function approaches negative infinity as you approach x=0 from the left.Therefore, the limit does not exist as the right-side limit is not equal to the left-side limit.

Answer (score 0):

You could write,
$$\lim_{x^+\to0}\frac{1}{x}=+\infty$$
 And,
$$\lim_{x^-\to0}\frac{1}{x}=-\infty$$
Hence, 
$$\lim_{x^+\to0}\frac{1}{x}\neq \lim_{x^-\to0}\frac{1}{x} $$
Therefore, limit doesnot exist.